# Get parent of the script tag from inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery

From inside a javascript file, how can we detect the parent of this script tag without any id and class by jquery.

```
(function() {
    $(this).parent('div').attr('id');
})();
```

Comment: what is parent html you mean? show us the code

Comment: provide jsfiddle or some code

Comment: you can't if I understand you

Comment: parent of the `script` tag will either `body` or `head` as far I know. Anything else can be parent?

Comment: `$(this).parent().get(0).tagName`
I'm assuming you're talking about `$(this)` this.

Comment: <div id="abc"><script src="xyz"></script></div> Inside this script I want to know parent div id that is "abc".            <div class="parent">
    <script>
        var scriptTags = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        var parentTag = scriptTags[scriptTags.length-1].parentNode;
        alert(parentTag.className);
    </script>
</div>                                                                above code is not working in ie.

Comment: Thanks Prathvi but this is not working in ie-9.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```html
<div class="parent">
    <script>
        var scriptTags = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        var parentTag = scriptTags[scriptTags.length-1].parentNode;
        alert(parentTag.className);
    </script>
</div>
```

Note that you have to get the script tags at once and not on DOM ready.

Answer (score 0):

In one line jQuery: `var script = jQuery('script').last().parent();`

#### Note:

Do NOT cast this in ready event, because then the last script might not be the script you are searching for.